# Flutter How to block dismiss dialog inside Dialog Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to display a custom dialog through a button. But i don't want user dismiss the dialog when touching exterior area.

I know that `barrierDismissible: false,` works but only in showDialog widget. In this case i need to do that but in Dialog widget.

This is what i have:

```
//RC
class ShowDialogGameOver2RC extends StatefulWidget {
  ShowDialogGameOver2RC({required this.score});

  late int score;

  @override
  State<ShowDialogGameOver2RC> createState() => _ShowDialogGameOver2RC();
}


// class dialog GameOver
class _ShowDialogGameOver2RC extends State<ShowDialogGameOver2RC> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(

      barrierDismissible: false //it doesn't work

      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      elevation: 2,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: _buildChild(context),
    );
  }
```

Comment: How do you show this ShowDialogGameOver2RC Widget as a popup? You may need to pass the dismissible flag there.

Comment: yes, it shows as a popup

Comment: Dialog is just a Widget, rendered like any other widget.  Could you add the code where you create your ShowDialogGameOver2RC, please?

Comment: ok, i've added it now

Answer (score 1):

Use Stack and place 1st widget as  `GestureDetector`

```dart
class _ShowDialogGameOver2RCState extends State<ShowDialogGameOver2RC> {
  bool showDialog = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                showDialog = !showDialog;
              });
            },
          ),
          if (showDialog)
            Dialog(
              // barrierDismissible: false //it doesn't work

              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              elevation: 2,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: [Text("tada")],
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i am not working with showDialog widget. I am working with only Dialog

Comment: Try current snippet